# Parsing JSON with AFNetworking into NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am trying to parse some JSON with AFNetworking and an NSDictionary. However something seems strange with the JSON. The JSON contains routes for shuttles, but I do not see a 'route' in the JSON.

When I run this code I get an empty NSDictionary with 15 allocated spaces.

```
NSString *methodURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@GetRoutesForMapWithSchedule", BASE_URL];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:methodURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    _routes = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
    //_route = _routes[@"Stops"];

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Can anyone explain how I can get all the info for one route? [This](http://uofubus.com/Services/JSONPRelay.svc/getroutesformapwithschedule) is the JSON.

```
    NSArray *routes = (NSArray *)responseObject;

    NSDictionary *oneRoute = responseObject[0];
    NSDictionary *stops = oneRoute[@"Stops"];
```

Comment: You're missing your model class. You would normally use that class to serialize the json data into the model class you built

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @jakepeterson This has nothing to do with the problem. He may have a model class that he didn't post because it isn't pertinent.

Comment: @jakepeterson - Not in Objective-C, you wouldn't.

Comment: Find an online JSON formatter to format/indent that JSON so you can understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the top level JSON object is actually an array, not a dictionary as you're trying to cast it to. Each element of the array on the other hand, is a dictionary.

Here is some code to get the general data structure and to get a piece of data out of one of the routes.

```
NSArray *routes = (NSArray *)responseObject;

NSDictionary *firstRoute = responseObject[0];
NSString *description = firstRoute[@"Description"];
```

**Edit:** To parse `Stops`, you would do something like this:

```
NSArray *stops = firstRoute[@"Stops"];
NSDictionary *firstStop = stops[0];
NSString *stopDescription = firstStop[@"Description"];
```

Comment: I tried to get all the stops but seem to be doing it wrong, I've updated my question could you take a look?

Comment: "Stops" is also an array, of dictionaries. Updating my answer to show you how to parse that. You need to look at the structure of your JSON to see what kind of objects are in it. Square brackets (`[]`) indicate an array, and squiggly brackets (`{}`) that have key-value pairs separated by colons (`:`) are dictionaries.